# OLAP Cube - Data Cube

Tags: database, data-warehouse, olap

I have a quick question regaring OLAP cubes or data cubes.
When I look at the [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP_cube#/media/File:OLAP_pivoting.png) I do not really understand "where" the represented data on the cube is. I guess this one is on the surface, right? Otherwise rotating the cube would not show completely different values.

So, my question is, what data is stored "in the cube?"

Should it not be sth like:

```
f(x,y,z) -> value (1)
```

and the value is inside a cell? But here I see only

```
f(x,y) -> surfacevalue (2a)

f(x,z) -> surface value (2b)

f(y,z) -> surface value (2c)
```

so, what is actually stored in the cube? All mappings (1 - 2c).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there are a lot of confusing terms connected to OLAP databases.  Cubes is one of the worst offenders because it is applied to all databases, regardless of the number of dimensions.  This is despite the fact you might reasonably assume a cube refers to a 3-dimensional object.

Cube, in this context, is used as a metaphor and shouldn't be considered literally.  It is used because it hard to illustrate/imagine objects with more than 3 dimensions.

A 1-dimensional dataset could be represented like this:

```
        10.00   15.00   16.00
--------------------------------
Year    2014    2015    2017
```

Here we can see a measure plotted against year.

2-dimensions could be illustrated like so:

```
Region  1 |   5.00    2.00    4.00
        2 |   5.00    5.50    5.00
        3 |   0.00    7.50    5.00
----------|--------------------------
Year      |   2014    2015    2017
```

Now we can see the same measure plotted against year and region.

3-dimensions can be thought of as a cube.  The [Wikipedia picture you linked to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP_cube#/media/File:OLAP_pivoting.png) is a good example of this.

Now we get to the higher dimensions were examples are hard/impossible to generate on a 2d screen.  In practice 4/5/6/etc dimensional reports are often presented as a 2d report, with a series of filters applied, limiting the returned records and totals.

Example:

```
Department:   Marketing
Customer Age: 18 - 24

Region  1 |   1.15    1.50    0.00
        2 |   2.75    4.01    1.25
        3 |   0.00    0.00    1.14
----------|--------------------------
Year      |   2014    2015    2017
```

This shows our measure with 2 additional filters.  It is now a 4d report.

The cube concept is trying to express that there are layers to the data, which you can navigate through.

Dr Rob Meredith, of Monash University, talks about this very subject on one of his [podcasts](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/podcast/fit5095-data-warehousing/id306569323?mt=2).  I think it's about half way through `Semester 1, 2009 - Episode 3` or `Semester 1, 2009 - Episode 4`.

Comment: Get's really confusing when you can just create the same OLAP structure in a database versus using OLAP software to do it. Essentially, creating a OLAP data mart that is processed within the same star schema versus using software like SQL Server Analysis Services to build, process, store, and provide access to said cube for reporting. However, there are pros and cons to doing that. SSAS for example aims to preprocess that data and make it lightning fast for said reporting.